# How to make soap request without namespace and soap action?

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I want to make wdsl soap request with name-space and soap action.
How i can achieve these?

I want to achieve below request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.api.sdp.ericsson.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:purchaseConsumeProduct>//Method name
         <userId>97XXXXXXX</userId>
         <serviceId>S-KXXXXX</serviceId>
         <premiumResourceType>MP-xxx-xx-xxxx-Sub-B2-D-xx</premiumResourceType>
         <productId>Daily MAP Test Sub V2 IN</productId>
         <purchaseMetas>
            <key>du:assetDescription</key>    
            <value>Subscription</value>
         </purchaseMetas>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <billingMetas>
            <key>du:assetID</key>
            <value>-</value>
         </billingMetas>
           <billingMetas>
            <key>du:contentType</key>
            <value>mobileApp</value>
         </billingMetas>
         <billingMetas>
            <key>du:channel</key>
            <value>COMMERCE_API</value>
         </billingMetas>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <usageMetas>
            <key>du:externalid</key>
            <value>S-XXXXXX</value>
         </usageMetas>
      </ws:purchaseConsumeProduct>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Where call URL :  "https://94.206.70.106:8181/cxf/services/UnifiedPartner?wsdl";

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Without 

When i removed name-space and soap-action then i got null error.

Comment: @ViramP I don't think you can call it without Namespace and Soap Action. They are required. What is your issue with giving these values?

Comment: Here,
I have to call without namespace for method.
I have achieved this using predefined XML files which contain above details and dynamically changed values according to requirements.